# Creating a PNG file from 1 byte console outputed image in MVS C++

Tags: c++

I am extracting the MNIST dataset using C++ and outputting it to the console using this.

```
// show a random character
int ind;
/* initialize random seed: */
srand(time(NULL));

/* generate secret number: */
ind = rand() % number_of_images;

cout << "" << endl;
cout << "Opening a  example: " << endl;
cout << +labels[ind] << endl;
cout << "" << endl;


// 28 rows
for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) 
{
    // 28 cols
    for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++) 
    {
        if (dataset[ind][i * 28 + j] > 80)
        {
            cout << 1;
            SetPixel();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << 0;
        }
    }
    cout << "" << endl;
}
system("pause");
```

I tried to create it using various methods, but all of them are too complicated. I just need to include a function or a method that will write a pixel to the file with I and J beeng the coordinates and the (if dataset) beeng eather a white pixel or a black pixel. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It sounds like your dataset contains images. Why not present each image via some image presentation function?

Comment: The general approach is to construct an image (bitmap) in memory, then use a library to create a file from the image.  Some image libraries may have functions that allow you to manipulate an image (setting pixels).

Comment: What's the question? If you want to make a png, have you tried libpng?

Comment: I wanted to try some libraries like PNG Writer and png++ and lodePNG but all of them are extremely tedious to install on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The file `train-images.idx3-ubyte` seems to have 16 bytes of header data at the start and then 784 bytes for each image of 28x28 pixels.

If you want to make `PNG` files, the easiest thing to do is write a **NetPBM** Portable Gray Map (`PGM`) file as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) and let **ImageMagick** or **Irfanview** or **Photoshop** convert the resulting PGM files to PNGs.

So, your program just needs to output a `PGM` header at the start like this:

```
P5
28 28
255
```

followed by the 768 bytes of image that you are currently writing to the console, then save that as `SomeFile.pgm`. You can then convert one of those to `PNG` using **ImageMagick**:

```
magick SomeFile.pgm -negate SomeFile.png
```

Or you can convert a whole directory full of `PGM` files into their corresponding `PNG` files, still with **ImageMagick** but its `mogrify` tool this time:

```
magick mogrify -format PNG -negate *.pgm
```

If you can get on a Linux, or other decent (non-Windows) system you can extract them all like this without writing any C at all:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove the 16 byte header
dd if=train-images.idx3-ubyte bs=16 iseek=1 > nohead

# Extract all 10,000 images to PNG
for ((i=0;i<10000;i++)) ; do
   echo $i
   { printf "P5\n28 28\n255\n"; dd if=nohead bs=784 iseek=$i count=1 2>/dev/null ; } | magick pgm:- -negate $i.png
done
```

Comment: Again, libraries and even external programs for convertion. I know that there is a way of doing it by creating an (unsigned char) with 4 bits ABGR format for png and streaming the whole thing inside a file. The thing is that i can't come up with the code, and I don't know how to initialize the PNG header for file to understand that it is indeed a PNG file